# Saving Umlauts in a .csv in R

Tags: r, csv, utf-8, diacritics

I am trying to save a dataframe into a csv file. The dataframe contains umlauts, which I want to keep.

I tried exporting with

```
write.csv2(x, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

as well as

```
readr::write_csv2(x)
```

in both cases, the umlauts do not get exported correctly. Instead of ä weird symbols occur: Ã¤ .  My R is set to save files as UTF-8 as well. Is there something else I can try?

Comment: What does `do not get exported correctly` mean? UTF8 works which is why I can type Αυτό Εδώ knowing it will appear properly. Almost all web pages are UTF8

Comment: Where does the input come from?

Comment: Instead of ä weird symbols occur: Ã¤

Comment: Its from a dataset I use with. I checked the file manually and changed it, where it had errors. After exporting, the errors are back up.

Comment: This means you're *reading the file as ASCII*. In UTF8 characters beyond the US-ASCII range are encoded using two or more bytes. `Ã` is how one of those bytes appear when you try to read it as if it was a single-byte codepage, eg Latin1

Comment: so this should do the trick in R? read.csv2(x, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")